# Creating an Accurate Timer in Javascript, but I sometimes get a negative Interval Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, timer, ecmascript-6

I can't use alot of the NPM libraries out there for an accurate timer as it relies on Node which I'm not using.. but the formula is pretty simple.  Here's a JSfiddle of what I'm using:

http://jsfiddle.net/zryNf/9/

```
setPercentageBar(page) {
    if (this.state.pagesById[page.id].active) {
      let pagesByIdCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.pagesById);
      let pageCopy = pagesByIdCopy[page.id];

      let percent = (100.0 / parseFloat(page.durationTime)) / 10;
      pageCopy.percentage += percent;
      this.setState({pagesById: pagesByIdCopy});

      pageCopy.progressBarNextAt += this.progressBarTime;  // this.progressBarTime = 100

      console.log('start time');
      console.log(pageCopy.progressBarStart);
      console.log('next at');
      console.log(pageCopy.progressBarNextAt);
      console.log('drift');
      console.log((new Date().getTime() - pageCopy.progressBarStart) % 100);
      console.log('Date().getTime():');
      let currTime = new Date().getTime();
      console.log(currTime);
      console.log('interval time');
      console.log(pageCopy.progressBarNextAt - currTime);
      console.log('--------------------------------------------------------\n');

      if (pageCopy.percentage < 100) {
        pageCopy.progressBarTimer = setTimeout(() => this.setPercentageBar(pageCopy),
          pageCopy.progressBarNextAt - currTime);
      }
    }
  }
```

It's not the exact code as I'm doing this in React, but it's the exact same formula.

I except use a 100ms delay as I am using this to update a progress bar and I need the progress bar to roll out smoothly.

I'm logging the startTime, nextAt time, drift, and interval time and it always started out well.  But at some point.. the interval times become negative and i don't know why!  And then everything starts messing up from that point forward.  I've tried multiple formulas of this accurate timer and it happens everytime eventually.  Once the interval time becomes negative.. they all become negative.

Anyone have an idea why and what can i do to fix it?

here are some example logs

https://pastebin.com/Cpfpf1Gp

EDIT: i have at most 5 timers going at 100ms each

Comment: Timers are never precise... And new Date isnt either... https://johnresig.com/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/

Comment: In your fiddle you write "this one works!", so what is the question?

Comment: @trincot looking at the logs i posted on the pastebin.. you can see the interval at some point turns negative and i'm trying to figure out why it's doing that so I can fix this.

Comment: @Jonasw i figured.. i feel like there should be some sort of solution to this though.

Comment: In the fiddle you never update `start` a second time, so there is no way `new Date().getTime()` can become less than `start`, which is the only way to get a negative outcome for the `%` operator. I think your problematic code has something essential that you did not include in the fiddle.

Comment: @trincot the fiddle is actually someone elses.. as I was trying to explain in my OP that i'm not using that code line per line.. but i'm using that exact formula in my own code.. but in a react/js setting.. but also i'm applying it to 5 different elements running at 100ms... if that makes sense at all.. i will recreate the issue and post the logs with also the new Date().getTime()

Comment: How do you expect us to analyse the problem if you provide just the logs of the problem, and code that evidently does not produce the problem and is not your code? You'll have to provide something with which we can reproduce it.

Comment: @trincot good point.  updated the OP

Comment: you guys who downvoted are horrible to this community.  people are just trying to get help here.  if we're not asking properly but we're genuinely trying to give all the information we can why downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the `setTimeout` callback function will be executed at exactly the desired time. If at that time other JavaScript code is running, that will first have to run to completion before the next event in the event queue gets processed, and a timer event is such an event.

So it might well be that you get the following scenario:

- At 0ms: `currTime` is 0, `progressBarNextAt` is 100, and you call `setTimeout(progressBarNextAt, 100)`. All is perfect.
- At 1ms: The next event in the event queue is some callback for the real processing that is happening
- At 220ms: that callback finishes, the next event in the event queue is the timer (which is late), and your function `setPercentageBar` gets called a second time
- At 221ms: `progressBarNextAt` is increased from 100 to 200, which is not enough as we are already passed that moment. You print an interval time of -21.

There can even be some asynchronous code scheduled *before* the timer event gets processed, in the form of micro tasks. For instance, if the processing in the second bullet point has some promises that resolve immediately, the corresponding `then` callback functions will still execute as part of that task, and only when all of those have executed, will the timer event get its turn.

Note also that non-JS factors can influence how long a certain task takes. If the machine gets in a heavy load, and the operating system reallocates resources, this may impact an otherwise light JavaScript task. Browsers also tend to delay the processing of timer events when the window in question is not on the foreground. And there can be still other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question seems to have taken something very simple and made it a bit complicated. Instead of trying to patch up that complexity with a "drift" calculation, why don't we take a simpler approach?

The key point is to decouple these two things:

1. When to update the progress bar.
2. How to calculate the current percentage or fraction of completion.

Instead, let's just have an `update()` function that can be called at any time and will always do the right thing. Its calculation will not depend at all on how often or when we call it.

Also, when you use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` for animation, you're likely to get some fairly jumpy results. We can use `requestAnimationFrame()` instead for a smoother animation. (It's still not perfect, but it's better than you'll get with a timer.)

So it might look like something like this:

```js
function progressBar( duration ) {
    setValue( 0 );
    var startTime = +new Date;
    update();
    function update() {
        var elapsed = +new Date - startTime;
        if( elapsed > duration ) elapsed = duration;
        if( elapsed < duration ) requestAnimationFrame( update );
        setValue( elapsed / duration );
    }
    function setValue( fraction ) {
        var percent = Math.floor( fraction * 100 );
        document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML =
            percent + '%';
        document.getElementById('filler').style.width =
            fraction * 100 + '%';
    }
}

progressBar( 5000 );
```

```css
#border {
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}

#filler {
    background-color: green;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
  <div id="filler">
      &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
<div id="percent"><div>
```